# Unable to install IBM mobile first studio

Tags: eclipse

I am not able to install worklight 6.3 studio on eclipse kepler.
System specifications: 32 bit windows 7 machine with 4 GB ram.

I am getting the below error. Any help will be appreciated.

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.launching,1.0.300.v20140203-1328
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.ui,3.5.400.v20140203-1328
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity,1.2.11.v201401230755
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.dbdefinition.genericJDBC,1.0.2.v201310181001
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda,3.4.2.v201311051159
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile,3.1.7.v201311081026
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile.ui,3.1.9.v201309221054
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile,3.2.9.v201307270622
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core,1.2.8.v201401230755
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.luw,1.0.3.v201401170830
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.luw.dbdefinition,1.0.6.v201401290336
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.luw.ui,1.0.6.v201402010752
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.msft.sqlserver,1.0.3.v201308161009
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.msft.sqlserver.ui,1.0.4.v201308031011
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws,1.2.6.v201307051812
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws.ui,1.2.6.v201308091040
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.ui,1.2.7.v201309031044
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.oda.cshelp,1.1.2.v201309200751
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result,1.1.6.v201402080246
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqlbuilder,1.0.7.v201401250704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.9.0.201308190730
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf,2.6.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ant,2.8.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen,2.9.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,2.9.1.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui,2.9.1.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ui,2.6.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.9.2.v20131212-0545
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common.ui,2.8.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.converter,2.6.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.databinding,1.3.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.databinding.edit,1.3.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.9.2.v20131212-0545
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change,2.9.0.v20131212-0545
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change.edit,2.5.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit,2.8.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.editor,2.9.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,2.9.1.v20131212-0545
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.9.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui,2.9.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.exporter,2.7.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer,2.8.1.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.ecore,2.7.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.java,2.7.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.rose,2.7.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping,2.7.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore,2.6.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore.editor,2.6.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2ecore,2.7.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2ecore.editor,2.6.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2xml,2.7.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2xml.ui,2.6.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ui,2.6.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef,3.9.0.201308190730
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt,3.9.1.v20140221-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core,3.9.2.v20140114-1555
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user,3.9.1.v20140205-0929
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.launching,3.7.1.v20131218-1102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.ui,3.9.2.v20131106-1600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.ui,1.3.1.v201401172016
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.doc.user,3.2.1.v201309042005
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.annotate,1.0.1.v201308281654
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.branding,3.3.2.v201401172016
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core,3.3.2.v201401172016
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db,2.2.1.v201311210236
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.branding,3.3.2.v201401172016
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core,2.3.1.v201308281654
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.ui,2.3.1.v201308272012
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui,3.3.2.v201401172016
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee,1.1.710.v201401281800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core,1.3.10.v201310231400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ui,1.1.710.v201312231800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web,1.1.701.v201401101700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jee,1.0.601.v201401082230
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui,1.0.601.v201401151036
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core,1.2.602.v201401151909
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui,1.1.801.v201307171524
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core,1.1.405.v20131208_1453
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas,1.2.101.v201402052019
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis.consumption.core,1.0.408.v201401152057
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis.consumption.ui,1.0.701.v201311011642
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.consumption.ui,1.1.702.v201312022107
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.core,1.0.502.v201310152235
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.ui,1.0.601.v201309040304
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde,3.8.100.v20140221-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.api.tools,1.0.501.v20130807-1634
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui,1.0.401.v20130730-1957
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.core,3.9.1.v20130628-1111
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.doc.user,3.9.2.v20140205-0929
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.launching,3.6.101.v20130807-1445
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.core,2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa,2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql,2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore,1.2.302.v201311131500
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.core,1.1.702.v201312092033
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.ui,1.0.801.v201307171524
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui,1.0.801.v201308100603
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.core,1.1.702.v201401301446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.ui,1.0.801.v201307171524
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core,1.3.1.v201401291437
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui,1.1.401.v201401171657
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.core,1.0.700.v201307162035
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.support.jsp,1.0.600.v201307162035
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.ui,1.0.700.v201308282108
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.core,1.5.100.v20140109_1422
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery,1.0.401.v20140204_1519
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.ui,1.4.200.v20140106_1456
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.802.v201401101620
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,1.3.201.v201401132128
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.501.v201311151800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui,1.2.401.v201310231535
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web,1.1.701.v201401101700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.801.v201308100603
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui,1.1.401.v201308132110
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xsd,2.9.1.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xsd.edit,2.6.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-7C7k9JEt1bytb7gki_vW6cRXAAJ
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.designer.core.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-7B7C7YCcNBGYD_FZD_ba
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.designer.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-4137w312412222241
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-7H7D7dCcNBHTESGlDZXh
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.doc.user,1.11.2.v201309171554-47C18w95FHAM87EJJD7
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.apache.derby.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-777A8iBmKFQ3NjRaMjbx8GDI
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-7J9e7UBWygSKz-9eahqEBz03G8sU
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.hsqldb.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-67F2AqGDM7KfNWJjJS8GDI
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm,1.0.0.v201401170830
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2,1.0.0.v201401170830
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.feature,1.11.2.v201401180622-7G-7bFD3wThz-VPpBasr2
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ingres.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-540AkF78Z7UCRAQDB
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.jdbc.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-4-49oB58B7DAF7FCH
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.jdt.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-2-07w312218332612
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.msft.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-5478AkF7AO7UBQAK8M
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.mysql.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-5478AkF7AK8X9JCREG
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.designer.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-337C8s73593K3F53B7
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-7A7T7GDZRDKKEgFnGiJR
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oracle.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-548fAkF7AL7RBJANAI
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.postgresql.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-553AkF7AK8PCRBQBP
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sap.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-540AkF7AJ7YEJBU7S
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sqlite.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-542AkF7AJ7SAKAPBF
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sybase.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-7E478F9NiNc2S7fxRCTD
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-7707GCcNBHLDaKTEcRi
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.data.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-647ABgJ9EKDJDNAdHO
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.ddl.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-27A178B08EG8S_IRVNeUiL6au
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.ddlgen.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-7A-7DF7RZHQUMdThK5_t
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-7N8I7WFDri5sjCyg6Q61VhVsihvO
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.parsers.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-623BgJ9EE9ZJRDZLA
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.results.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-427H9oB58F6A8I5KGJ
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.schemaobjecteditor.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-4218375LG5BJ93413
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.sqlbuilder.feature,1.11.2.v201309171554-79-7FEVVFNSI_QiI-Sd
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.9.1.201308190730
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,2.9.1.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui,2.9.1.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen,2.9.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ui,2.7.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.9.2.v20131212-0545
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.common.ui,2.8.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.converter,2.9.1.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.databinding.edit,1.3.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.databinding,1.3.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit,2.8.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.editor,2.9.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.9.2.v20131212-0545
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.9.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui,2.9.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf,2.9.2.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore.editor,2.8.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore,2.7.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping,2.7.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ui,2.7.0.v20140203-1126
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.transaction,1.4.0.201306111400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.validation,1.7.0.201306111341
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.workspace,1.5.1.201306111400
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.gef,3.9.1.201308190730
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.common.core,1.7.0.201306111432
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.clipboard.core,1.7.0.201306111432
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.commands.core,1.7.0.201306111432
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.core,1.7.0.201306111432
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.type.core,1.7.0.201306111432
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jdt,3.9.2.v20140221-1700
No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.jdt_root,3.9.2.v20140221-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.common.feature,1.3.1.v201401172016-67A0AkF7BJ7QCRAKHT
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.feature,3.3.2.v201401172016-7K7P6EVVFNcGtPALhbkMNGD
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.feature,3.3.2.v201401172016-7V7_7AFC7sRe9UHgWgXruCgd6
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature,3.5.2.v201311051900-7b7KIawFSK2WQyUFC2y01XXyUmRm
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.ext.feature,3.3.105.v20131208_1453-57CFGGAkF7BI8LDLLBHNQ
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.web_core.feature,3.5.2.v201311051900-7Q7GGbXFE9LeBYN3-od-Jt2kwz-0sN863877
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature,3.5.2.v201311051900-7F7GFVuC27Svmclpwjkc0enMD7nrQ9V2nvprn2h2
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.pde,3.9.1.v20140221-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature,3.5.2.v201312050600-7B7EFSkF7RZHOoKlQwR7NJ
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature,3.5.2.v201310231535-7C7BFeGEdhOaxlXh9oUj1pLmRxS8OK
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature,1.5.2.v201401171657-7H7FFhXFC7sReuSlgtfhew
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_core.feature,3.3.300.v20131206_1548-34F8S8s7358384La2533
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature,3.3.302.v20140204_1502-7B7AFRGAtNe9vEHKb-OaTZyg8E94
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_core.feature,3.5.2.v201401062113-7E7KF_fAJz0nDYOr4pKSKvNVwbvbvUz
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature,3.5.2.v201401062113-7O7QG3wEMkBS3Graz0gRCYqCz-PVayJqBmOpb93L
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.ws_ui.feature,3.5.2.v201312021609-7I7EFk_EtEo_L0G8-I7p3FPGpvnnteWuy61GjVZN
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature,3.5.2.v201401062113-7C7OFvVF7RZHQXIlNxNyPh
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature,3.5.2.v201401062113-7H7IFizDxumVu0K6bjdPjXRkoz0FiUYMnSyT9PL

Thank u in advance

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Eclipse issue, it also occurs sometime even if you install Android ADT, you can uncheck the "**contact all update sites during install to find required software**"  box, then it should be good to go

[image]

Comment: Thank u. It worked. Now I am facing new issue while migrating my project to MFP. The error is as below :
E: Migrating the myTimeProject project from version 6.0.0 to version 6.3.0.00.20141127-1357 has failed because Cannot parse E:\WL6.3Workspaces\BeiginingWkspaceKepler\myTimeProject\apps\myTime\ipad\native\myTimeProjectMyTimeIpad-Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

That does not look related to MFP at all. The error is the same for everything in log - "No repository found containing..."; It looks like an Eclipse Marketplace issue.